# XLSX removing sheets OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: apache-poi, xlsx

I am trying to load the XLSX file using POI library that has 5 sheets. Size of the file is 5 MB. Total records in all sheets are around 30,000.
Once the file is loaded i need to delete the 1 or more sheets on the fly based on sheet neame as input.

Here is the snippet.

```
 public void generateReportWorkBook(String[] requestedReports) throws Exception {
      // Read the file
      String dailyTicketReport = ReportConstants.REPORT_PATH + ReportConstants.FILE_NAME + ReportConstants.XLSX_FILE_EXTN;

      FileInputStream fis = null;
      XSSFWorkbook book  = null;

      try {
          fis = new FileInputStream(dailyTicketReport);

          book = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
          for (int i = book.getNumberOfSheets() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
              XSSFSheet tmpSheet = book.getSheetAt(i);
              if (!ArrayUtils.contains(requestedReports, tmpSheet.getSheetName())) {
                  book.removeSheetAt(i);
              }
          }
      } catch (Exception e) {
          logger.error("Error occured while removing the sheets from workbook");
          throw e;
      } finally {
          IOUtils.closeQuietly(fis);
      }
    }
```

When i execute the program. I get OutofMemory Exception.
How can i remove the sheets without memory issue.

Comment: What is your heap size set to? And if you care about memory, why are you using an InputStream instead the File directly? The [documentation clearly states that File uses less memory than InputStream](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)...

Comment: Use File instead of InputStream and u can go for SXSSFWorkbook() if u have more records.Workbook workBook = new SXSSFWorkbook();

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue of OOM while parsing xlsx file...after two days of struggle, I finally found out the below code that was really perfect;

This code is based on sjxlsx. It reads the xlsx and stores in a HSSF sheet.

```
            // read the xlsx file
       SimpleXLSXWorkbook = new SimpleXLSXWorkbook(new File("C:/test.xlsx"));

        HSSFWorkbook hsfWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

        org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet hsfSheet = hsfWorkbook.createSheet();

        Sheet sheetToRead = workbook.getSheet(0, false);

        SheetRowReader reader = sheetToRead.newReader();
        Cell[] row;
        int rowPos = 0;
        while ((row = reader.readRow()) != null) {
            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row hfsRow = hsfSheet.createRow(rowPos);
            int cellPos = 0;
            for (Cell cell : row) {
                if(cell != null){
                    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell hfsCell = hfsRow.createCell(cellPos);
                    hfsCell.setCellType(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    hfsCell.setCellValue(cell.getValue());
                }
                cellPos++;
            }
            rowPos++;
        }
        return hsfSheet;
```

Comment: please don't copy the exact same post to several questions - chances are that either they don't really fit all or the questions are duplicates (and should be flagged as such)